# Laravel nested: Events (with Timelines) and with subevents (with Timelines)

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have Events that can have subevents, and each event can have Timeline items.
Looking for a way to get a nested collection.

For events I can get them with the timeline items:

```
App\Event::with('timelines')->get()
```

For events I can them with nested subevents:

```
App\Event::doesntHave('parent')->with('subEvents')->get()
```

How can I combine the two?

Expected end result:
each event includes
1) the timeline items for that event, and
2) the subevents for that event (and for each subevent: the timeline items for that subevent).

E.g. :

```
- Event 1
  - Timeline: 1, 3, 5
  - subEvents:
    - 2, Timeline: 2, 6
    - 3, Timeline: 7, 8
- Event 4
  - Timeline: 9
- Event 5
  - subEvents:
    - 6, Timeline: 10
```

Also fine to get the results and use collection grouping. A la `App\Event::with('timelines')->get()->groupBy('parent_id')`, but having trouble getting to the wanted structure.

Comment: what does the current returned result look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make this structure.

```
- Event 1
  - Timeline: 1, 3, 5
  - subEvents:
    - 2, Timeline: 2, 6
    - 3, Timeline: 7, 8
- Event 4
  - Timeline: 9
- Event 5
  - subEvents:
    - 6, Timeline: 10
```

You can retrieve timelines from `Event` model, as well as the `subEvents` with their timelines.  In order to make that you can create a function for `subEvents` retrieval.

```
App\Event::with(['timelines','subEvents' => function($q){
   $q->with('timelines');
])->get();
```

or **this** if you don't need to make any queries in subEvents.

```
App\Event::with('timelines','subEvents.timelines')->get();
```

Make sure, that your Model's **relationships** must be like this:

```
//Event.php
class Event extends Model
{
    public function timelines(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Timeline');
    }

    public function subEvents(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\SubEvent');
    }
}

//SubEvent.php
class SubEvent extends Model
{
    public function timelines(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Timeline');
    }
}
```

I think, this might help you a bit.

Comment: This helped a lot! `App\Event::doesntHave('parent')->with('subEvents','subEvents.timelines')->get()` is what I needed. Small correction for the `subEvents()` function: I have it as `return $this->hasMany(Event::class, 'parent_id')`.

Comment: Yes that works the same, with your code. I'm glad that I helped you !!